# Modeling human behavior in video game

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create a bot that mimics my playing behavior. The game is real time. I have access to the game's internal state. The player has a set of actions that they can perform.

Implementing an if/then decision tree bot based on the games state is easy to do, but it does not result in a realistic human player.

I though using machine learning and neural networks could solve this problem. My initial approach was to log the game's state and my actions every 100 ms. I fed a sequence of game states and my actions into a LSTM and attempted to predict what action should be performed in the next 100ms. The problem with this is that 95+% of the time, me (the player) is idle and not sending any input into the game. So the result of training is that the network predicts that the next action after a sequence of game states should be nothing/idle.

I thought about using a different approach where game state is only logged when the player sends an input. That way the network will not predict that the player should be idle. This misses out on potentially vital information in the game state when the player was not sending input.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach you can take is to use cost function weights to bring each action (i.e. idle and others) on equal footing. The problem here is presumably that you have an unbalanced dataset (in terms of labels) e.g. you might have 10 "idle" for each "jump" label/action that you have; this in return pushes the neural network to go with the dominant label.

In that case, you can set the class weights of your cross entropy as [1 10] i.e. inversely proportional to frequency of each label that you have. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy